# Using command/shell modules causes: ValueError: Key name may not begin with an underscore on multiple runs

Tags: ansible

Ansible throws an error on every task which uses the shell or command modules, but not when running for the first time on a new machine.

The process I use is to image a new raspberry pi, and then use ansible to set up the services that I need. Running ansible for the first time works fine, but if I run it again (without changing anything) it fails, saying `ValueError: Key name may not begin with an underscore`

Here is an example of a task that throws an error. Running `/usr/local/bin/pigpiod -v` on the remote machine works as expected/

```
- name: see if pigpiod is the correct version
  command: "/usr/local/bin/pigpiod -v"
  register: pigpiod_version
```

Here is the error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ValueError: Key name may not begin with an underscore
fatal: [issacs_box]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 113, in <module>\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 48, in invoke_module\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py\", line 170, in load_source\n    module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 626, in _exec\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 673, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_hc3z4iej/__main__.py\", line 292, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_hc3z4iej/__main__.py\", line 199, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_hc3z4iej/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 901, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_hc3z4iej/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2243, in _log_invocation\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_hc3z4iej/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2201, in log\n  File \"systemd/_journal.pyx\", line 68, in systemd._journal.send\n  File \"systemd/_journal.pyx\", line 32, in systemd._journal._send\nValueError: Key name may not begin with an underscore\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong PYPI package installed. Coincidentally, there is a package called `systemd` (version 0.16.1) which is different from the official `systemd-python` (version 234) package. Running `pip3 uninstall systemd` and then `pip3 install systemd-python --user` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a weird Ansible bug. What version are you using? Can you try to downgrade and/or upgrade a version. If that would fix this error, please notify the Ansible developers and create an issue at their repo.

Else, try to update and/or downgrade your Python version. It could be that something is wrong with this file `/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py`

Comment: I am using version 2.8 (the latest I believe). I tried downgrading to 2.7, but this made no difference. I don't know how to check the `imp.py` file to see if there is anything wrong, but it appears to be the original version.

Comment: Can you try running the playbook on another Ansible master node?